# How to build in a redirect if the browser is not mobile

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I want to redirect users to another page if they are loading my web app from a standard desktop browser. I've tried detection scripts using php and javascript in the index file which both work fine in the dev environment. The problem is when I use the 'sencha app build production' command to build the project I get errors. I'm assuming this is because the build script is somehow being redirected by these scripts when trying to build dependencies. I'm not sure how to fix this. I tried building it without the scripts then uploading the production build and adding the code to the uploaded files but the code added to the uploaded files seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Either the builder is getting redirected or the builder cannot follow the code dependencies to build a single JS file.

You can create a device profile for desktop which will redirect in the launch function when the profile is active: [Sencha Touch 2 device profiles](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/profiles)